# How to paint a wall without getting paint on the wallpaper frieze?

Tags: painting, repainting

I had a pipe crack and cause damage to a wall with the wallpaper frieze running along the top of the wall.  How do I repaint the wall without getting paint on the wallpaper.  I have looked at reviews for purple and yellow tape, which is suppose to be ok for wallpaper.  Unfortunately it seems like a lot of people have had problems.  Any advice or recommendation are greatly appreciated.

Comment: Are you asking us to forecast whether tape will work with your particular paper? 
Try it and see. We can't tell from here.

Comment: I've used a drywall trowel as a blocker to paint, and it works well with caveats, like wiping down the edge after every section and tiring your other arm while painting. If it's a small area, those concerns are minimal.

Comment: Ignoring if it will work with your wallpaper, most people have problems because they leave the tape on for weeks and months.

Answer (score 2):

Putting any tape on the wallpaper is risky. There is no guarantee that it will pull off without damaging the paper.

The answer is to not use tape.  I have used  [angle point artist brushes](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B08K415Z8H) to paint along the edge of wallpaper.  Sure the paint line is thin, ( about 1/2") but art brushes are easier to control.  Then with the edge done you can expand the cut-in line with a 1 1/2" or 2" brush.

Sure it takes longer and you have to be very careful, but this is how you don't damage wallpaper.

Comment: Thank you for the excellent advice.   Sincerely appreciate the help.  I would rather the job take longer than risk ruining the wallpaper.